# Access exported Typescript interfaces from declaration file

Tags: typescript

How do we access an interface defined in a declaration file? Eg. I'm having issues with the redux package. Take [the store declaration](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/index.d.ts#L114):

```
export interface Store<S> { ... }
```

However, in our own code we cannot type variables as `Store<S>` as

```
$ error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Store'.
```

Eg. in:

```
const addUser = (store: Store<number>) => {
  store.dispatch({type: "INCREMENT_USER_COUNT"})
}
```

But then, if we remove the `export` from the declaration file, the typing works fine:

```
interface Store<S> { ... }
```

Is there any way for me to actually use this interface as it is defined in the redux declaration file, without having to redefine the `Store` interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that's `export`ed from one file must be `import`ed to be consumed from another file.

Write `import { Store } from 'redux';` in the file you're consuming it from to use the type locally.